# Does SSL Handshake gives reliability of data?

Tags: java, spring, rest, ssl, spring-boot

I have a REST API which provides the data for an mobile app client.My web server has an SSL certificate.Is it ensured that if I do a SSL Handshake at the beginning then all the requests will get responses in the app side?Because My Controllers are Asynchronous and that make sure that all request will get response.But my concern is about all those responses will be delivered to the client without dropping or loss?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: SSL is encryption, not a transport protocol.

Comment: @KevinO "Transport Layer Security (TLS) and its predecessor, Secure Sockets Layer (SSL), both frequently referred to as "SSL", are cryptographic protocols" wikipedia definition though

Comment: Still not a [Transport Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_layer).

Comment: Oh I see then Here HTTP is the transport protocol.Sodoes Http ensures data reliability. I know HTTP is build over TCp but even are there any chances that HTTP Response which my API will send will fail or lost in between?

Comment: Well, let's ask this. Assume the person turns on air plane mode in the middle of a communication (since you said a mobile app). Is the response going to be delivered? What about driving into a tunnel? VPN drops?

Answer (score 1):

SSL/TLS  secures the transport against sniffing and manipulation, nothing more. But the underlying TCP protocol already provides some kind of reliability of the transport in that lost messages gets resent from the peer. Of course all of this does not help if the underlying layer is broken, for example when disconnecting the LAN cable from the computer.

And none of this provides reliability at the application level. For example it still can happen that the client sends a request and the server will never respond to it because the server just crashed.